# How to Average by day of week in Google Sheets?

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, average

Given a table of dates and values.

[image: Dates]

How to average by day of week?

[image]

I found `AVERAGEIF` to average and `TEXT(E4, "dddd")` to convert to day of week.

But how to combine those two functions?

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2001 | 1 |
| 1/2/2001 | 2 |
| 1/3/2001 | 3 |
| 1/4/2001 | 3 |
| 1/5/2001 | 6 |
| 1/6/2001 | 3 |

| Day of Week | Average |
| --- | --- |
| Sunday |  |
| Monday |  |
| Tuesday |  |
| Wednesday |  |
| Thursday |  |
| Friday |  |
| Saturday |  |

Comment: To combine results of two formulas you can use `HSTACK()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with `QUERY()` function. Try-

```
=QUERY({INDEX(TEXT(A1:A15,"dddd")),B1:B15},
"select Col1, avg(Col2) group by Col1 label Col1 'Day', avg(Col2) 'Average'")
```

To make it dynamic, use-

```
=QUERY({INDEX(TEXT(TOCOL(A1:A,1),"dddd")),TOCOL(B1:B,1)},
"select Col1, avg(Col2) group by Col1 label Col1 'Day', avg(Col2) 'Average'")
```

[image]

Comment: That works but how to make it start on Sunday?

Comment: Then you have to manually put day names from `Sunday` to `Saturday` in cells. Lets say put Sunday to D2 cell and down then use `INDEX(AVERAGEIFS($B$1:$B,TEXT($A$1:$A,"dddd"),D2))` formula to get average.

Comment: And this is for single cell formula. `=LAMBDA(wk,{wk,MAP(wk,LAMBDA(x,AVERAGEIFS(B1:B,INDEX(TEXT(A1:A,"dddd")),x)))})({"Sunday";"Monday";"Tuesday";"Wednesday";"Thursday";"Friday";"Saturday"})`.

Comment: `INDEX(AVERAGEIFS($B$1:$B,TEXT($A$1:$A,"dddd"),D2))` works well. Thank you. What does INDEX do? How to count the cells that have a value for each day? I tried `COUNTIFS` but it did not work.

Comment: Here `INDEX()` is equivalent of `ArrayFormula()`.

Comment: Assuming all the weekdays are included in your date list, you can do it with one formula `=QUERY(QUERY({INDEX(TEXT(TOCOL(A1:A,1),"dddd")),TOCOL(B1:B,1),INDEX(WEEKDAY(TOCOL(A1:A,1)))},
"select Col1, avg(Col2), Col3 group by Col1, Col3 order by Col3 label Col1 'Day', avg(Col2) 'Average'"),"select Col1, Col2")`